# Ubuntu 20.04 top bar icons stretched

Tags: gnome, icons, 20.04

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome 3.36.1 and the yaru-dark theme (default).
In the top bar, some non-default applications have vertically stretched icons, like what you see in this image showing Firefox Dev Edition and Zoom (on the left side the icons are stretched, on the right side you have some examples of correct sizing):

[image]

Both apps were not installed from the store (because they're not there). Firefox Dev Edition was installed by placing it into the /opt folder and creating a .desktop file that linked to the path. Zoom was installed using their .deb package.

How could I fix this? I tried changing the gnome theme, but it didn't helped.

Comment: The same happens with me when i start Virtualbox (installed via apt) I still can't figure the cause

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Would you be so kind as to [edit] your question to include an image that shows both an application with a vertically stretched image and one without for comparison purposes? Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Done, thank you for your help

Comment: same thing on Arch. I guess it's a bug in GNOME 3.36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of August 28th, 2020 it look like this bug has now been fixed (at least I don't see it anymore, and the only thing I did was updating the OS regularly).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a gnome-shell bug.
However value changes in text-scaling-factor would trigger top panel resize automatically and fix the icons distortion.

A workaround to fix the icon distortion in top panel.
Adding following script to "Startup Application Preference", it will be executed after login and changes text-scaling-factor value and reset.

--
#!/bin/bash

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor 1.01
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface text-scaling-factor

exit 0

Comment: Hi Peng, thank you very much for giving a workaround for this! I tried testing it by changing the text scaling factor in Gnome Tweaks, but the icons remained stretched. I wanted to try with the "Startup Application Preference", but I couldn't find this setting (or file). Could you point me on where to find these preferences?

Comment: You can check this topic and its answers: https://askubuntu.com/q/1269090/1037999 in order to run the script at startup

Comment: My icons were squished after an update, and this worked for me